# PostAsync hanging in Xamarin Forms works on emulator but hangs on actual Mobile phone

Tags: xamarin, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, async-await

I have Xamarin Forms project where I'm trying to POST and GET data to/from a Web API but when I'm making an async/await call, it works on the emulator (not without its original problems!) but when I try it on my actual phone mobile (Samsung S8+), it just hangs indefinitely.

Note that I'm only concentrating on the Android part right now, not iOS, not that the problem should make any difference in either.

This is the code I'm using:

***IDataService.cs***

```
Task<TResponse> PostDataAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(string uri, TRequest data)
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : class;
```

***DataService.cs:***

```
public async Task<TResponse> PostDataAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(string 
             additionalUri, TRequest data)
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : class
    {
        return await WebClient
        .PostData<TRequest, TResponse>
        (string.Concat(this.Uri, additionalUri), data);
    }
```

***WebClient.cs***

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    using (var response = await client.PostAsync(
        uri, 
        new StringContent(jsonData, 
            Encoding.UTF8, 
            "application/json" )))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content);
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 1:**

***LoginPageViewModel.cs***

```
public DelegateCommand SignInCommand => _signInCommand ??
       (this._signInCommand = new DelegateCommand(SignInCommandAction));


private async void SignInCommandAction()
{
    try
    {
        ....
        var user = await this._dataService
        .PostDataAsync<LoginRequestDto,
         LoginResponseDto>(@"Accounts/Login", loginRequestDto);     
         ....
    }
    ...
}
```

**Method2:**

***LoginPageViewModel.cs***

```
public DelegateCommand SignInCommand => _signInCommand ?? 
           (this._signInCommand = 
            new DelegateCommand(async () => await SignInCommandAction()));


private async Task SignInCommandAction()
{
    try
    {
        ....
        var user = await this._dataService
        .PostDataAsync<LoginRequestDto,
         LoginResponseDto>(@"Accounts/Login", loginRequestDto);     
         ....
    }
    ...
}
```

The PostDataAsync works with both methods when I call my local web API i.e. http://10.0.2.2/MyApp/api/ but both methods still hangs when calling external my web service from web provider i.e. http://myapp-123-site.atempurl.com/api/ which is a temp url for testing purpose.

The same apply to my GetDataAsync which is not demonstrated in question but I just thought I'd mention it.

Based on the above, you would think that my async/await code is correct since it works when calling the local web api but then what's causing it to hang when calling the remote web api.

As mentioned, I did enable my INTERNET permission in the manifest.

[image]

Any suggestions welcomed?

Thanks.

**UPDATE-1:**

Note that I've just tried to call a GET opertation within the same function and this is working in the emulator but hanging with the actual mobile.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                   .DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content);
        }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE-2:**

This is somehow working and I have no idea why! The only thing that comes to mind is that I upgraded my libraries. This included PRISM which may have been at the source of the problem but I have no idea.

Sorry I can't provide more details. I could role back my code and try to see if it's hanging again but I just don't have the time to go and experiment some more considering the amount of time I've already spent on this. Sorry.

Comment: Happened to me also. Check whether your device is connected to internet and check the internet permission also.

Comment: Can you try changing async void to async task in SignInCommandAction?

Comment: You might wanna use Tasks in place of voids for asynchronous programming !!

Comment: @WasifMahmoodMustafa my device is connected to my wireless at home and I believe internet access is now enabled by default, whether selected or not. I'll need to re-check that last statement just to be 100% sure but irrespective of that, I have selected the INTERNET permission in the manifest. I've just tried it at the office where I'm not connected to their wireless, and the same happens. Still hanging.

Comment: @PatrickGoode, I've tried that as well and will post an update later on with the actual code but it made no difference. async void should definitely be ok though when dealing with a ICommand or in my case a DeleteCommand as provided by PRISM. I use this in WPF and the now dead Windows Phone, and in UWP.

Comment: It looks like some code is missing, can you post all of it?  For example  this._dataService.PostDataAsync.

Comment: @PatrickGoode I've updated my answer with the details from the data service and both methods that I've used in my viewmodel. As mentioned in my question, both methods work locally which I didn't was the case but it is, so you would think async/await code is ok but why is it hanging on remote. Note that remote works when called from Postman, Fiddler, etc... so the remote web api is not the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

The requested url is an **IP** or a **domain** name.

- If it is ip, only the IP of the public network can be accessed by devices on multiple network segments.
- If it is a domain name, it needs to support the domain name resolution service.

If you do not have these environments for a while, you need the IP of the device and the IP of the server on the same network segment.

> The PostDataAsync works with both methods when I call my local web API i.e. http://10.0.2.2/MyApp/api/ but both methods still hangs when calling external my web service from web provider i.e. http://myapp-123-site.atempurl.com/api/ which is a temp url for testing purpose.

From this phenomenon , the reason should be the **temp url**. From this domain name (`myapp-123-site.atempurl.com`) can not find the right local IP (`10.0.2.2`).And when you test in local network , I guess this will work.However the network of actual mobile can be not the same with local network , such as using 3G/4G network , then this will not working.

Comment: I'm actually requesting data directly from a web API which I've published with my provider and I haven't registered a domain just yet as this is just a temp site so that I can test my web API with my xamarin forms app. The url looks something like: "http://username-site.atempurl.com/api/accounts/login". Note that the web api works a charm from Postman/Fiddler/Chrome/Edge/Firefox.

Comment: @Thierry Okey, have a try with mobile's browser to check whether can works .

Comment: I've tried it and it works perfectly well in my mobile browser. It's returning me json as expected. Note that I've tried it with Chrome and Edge and it's working with both. Any ideas?

Comment: @Thierry I have updated answer .I think the problem should be the temp url . If testing with local ip and keep the network in the same segment, actual device also can work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your update. 10.0.2.2 is, as far as I'm aware required to access the internet via the emulator (could be wrong but that was my understanding i.e. same as localhost - ish) but when I try it with the remote web api (i.e. http://...atempurl.com/api) on my mobile while a) connected to my wireless or b) connected to my 4G network, neither of them work and just hangs. Again, as far as I understood, 10.0.2.2 is only used for local test but it shouldn't be used for remote access of a web api. Isn't this correct?

Comment: @Thierry Yeah, 10.0.2.2 now is only used for local test , if want used for remote access need DNS to this IP .

Comment: I'm seriously confused. Sorry. If I want to access my remote web api, not via the emulator, but directly from my phone either via wi-fi or 4G, what do I need. You'd think that a) the fact that a web browser on pc, including phone can access http://...atempurl.com/api that some sort of DNS is setup since I'm not using the IP and b) it wouldn't just hang, no?

Comment: @Thierry Eh ,first I want to know server deployed in where .If in the cloud server , you do not need to set dns .Else if in local network ,then need to do that.

Comment: That's what I thought.. My remote one is deployed to Web service provider, so yes cloud, but that the part I don't get, why is hanging with this one and not the local one when access via 10.0.2.2. If it was a problem with async/await, you'd think it would hang for local and remote.

Comment: @Thierry Eh , even though is a cloud server , if not binded to the domain , will not access by domain name. From my previous comment , I said if a cloud server ,not need to set dns .That not means no binded domain can access form domain ,just means remote device can access by Ip.

Comment: Sorry @JuniorJian, but I just don't understand what you mean or what you want me to do to resolve me problem. Truly sorry and thanks so much for trying to help.

Comment: @Thierry Okey , if later solved remember to share solution here. :)

Comment: I thought I'd test if my mobile (not emulator) could access the web so I added a WebView to my login page and it worked, so I thought I'd click the login button and to my surprise, everything worked as expected. While I'm glad that it working, it's really annoying me that I've gone from "hanging" to "working" without knowing why?? Thank you for taking the time to help and sorry if I wasted your time! Note that the only thing I did was to upgrade all my libraries which may be the reason why it is now working.

Comment: @Thierry Thanks for replying .So the problem maybe the upgrade of libraries .If webview can work , I think this is not related to domain or dns .

Comment: I'm not sure it was related to controls after all as I managed to get the problem again but now I've got it to work both using local and my remote Web api. I think that my remote Web api dns wasn't available immediately but I think there is a bug in httpClient where it does not timeout. My code has not changed and it works as expected leaving to believe this is the problem. The same applies to lochost after I used a dodgy localhost url, it just hang but when correct, it works as expected. The odd thing is that depending on the uri I use, it does sometimes throw an error when making the request

Comment: @Thierry If occurs error log , having a look at log info to check where problem is.